# Silverlight: Difficulty with ListBox and {Binding} syntax

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm building a test Windows Phone 7 Silverlight app. (I've been following this [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx).) I'm having a problem binding the list items to item properties.

Get tweets for an entered username:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient twitter = new WebClient();
        twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
        twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(String.Format("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name={0}", username.Text)));
    }
```

Add those tweets to the listbox:

```
    struct TwitterItem
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    }

    void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        IEnumerable<TwitterItem> tweetItems = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                               select new TwitterItem   
                               {
                                   ImageSource = tweet.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                                   Message = tweet.Element("text").Value,
                                   UserName = tweet.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value
                               };

        listBox1.ItemsSource = tweetItems;

        PageTitle.Text = tweetItems.First().UserName;
    }
```

`PageTitle.Text` reveals that the tweets are being correctly parsed... but they aren't being displayed correctly.

Here is the listbox I'm trying to use:

```
        <ListBox Height="454" Width="418" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,128,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0" />
                        <StackPanel Width="370">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" Foreground="BlanchedAlmond" FontSize="28"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="shows up just fine" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The third `TextBlock` shows up just fine, so it's not an issue of having 0 height or width. I suspect that the problem is something with `Text={Binding Property}`. Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me in WPF... I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work in Silverlight. Did you check the Output window in VS in case there are binding errors ? Also, try to make TwitterItem a class rather than a struct. I'm not sure it has any impact, but it doesn't hurt to try...

Comment: @Thomas Levesque yes, there were binding errors. I didn't know to look there, thanks.

Comment: you should add your solution as an answer, then mark it accepted so people know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was defining TwitterItem as an inner class of MainPage, when it needed to be a top-level class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass in an ObservableCollection to listBox1.ItemsSource. Then the UI will update when you set it.

```
ObservableCollection<TwitterItem> o = new ObservableCollection<TwitterItem>();
foreach(TwitterItem t in tweetItems)
{
   o.Add(t);
}
listBox1.ItemsSource = o;
```

I believe I had the same issue in my app and this fixed it.

Comment: Did you actually read the question ? a. the problem was not that the list wasn't updating; b. the OP already solved his problem

Comment: Didnt see the last line in the question.

Comment: I did read it I swear. I just understood it completely wrong :)